# How to get center point from a set of points

Tags: geospatial

Plies help me. I have many points. I want to get a point that does not overlap or the center of that set of points. Any ideas?[set of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OVUO.jpg) i am using QGIS and R.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform functions like that using only points. You need to set up some polygons, lines or something similar first. Join up the points then perform your geospatial queries. QGIS has a good python API, you could code it in there:-

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/getting_started_with_pyqgis.html